# Download large file from S3 using API gateway?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am creating a webpage where users can click on different links, which will download files, ranging from 1 megabyte - 300+ megabytes. The links perform a GET request to an API gateway endpoint, which download the respective file from S3. I'm using the following code currently:

```
def files_download(event, context):
try:
    key = event['queryStringParameters']['key']
    # name = event
except Exception as e:
    return client_failure('Key field required as query parameter', e)

try:
    file = s3.Object('XXXXX', key)

    return success_file('text/csv', key, file.get()['Body'].read())
except Exception as e:
    return server_failure('Failed to retrieve file', e)

def success_file(content_type, attachment_name, data):
    return {
        'isBase64Encoded': False,
        'statusCode': 200,
        'headers': {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' : True,
            'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=' + attachment_name
        },
        'body': data
    }

def success(data):
    return {
        'isBase64Encoded': False,
        'statusCode': 200,
        'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' : True
        },
        'body': json.dumps({
            'data': data
        }, cls=DecimalEncoder)
    }

def server_failure(message, details):
    return {
        'isBase64Encoded': False,
        'statusCode': 500,
        'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' : True
        },
        'body': json.dumps({
            'message': message,
            'details': str(details)
        }, cls=DecimalEncoder)
    }

def client_failure(message, details):
    return {
        'isBase64Encoded': False,
        'statusCode': 400,
        'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' : True
        },
        'body': json.dumps({
            'message': message,
            'details': str(details)
        }, cls=DecimalEncoder)
    }
```

However, this seems to fail for large files (>100 MB). Is there any way to make it work, or is there a better way to allow users to download the files? I have thought about making my S3 bucket public and providing direct links, but obviously that is not ideal for authentication reasons.

Comment: I believe there is a secure way for users to download direct from S3 (via a temp token or something like that). Did you search at all?

Comment: Yep, I would look into generating a pre-signed url - https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3.html#generating-presigned-urls